# Choosing the highest scored results from a table variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

I have the following table variable in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @results TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        customerId int, 
                        salesId int, 
                        score int,
                        lastServiceDate datetime,
                        PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

I need an efficient way to clean the table or access the table's results, so that it returns only 1 result per salesId.  If there is more than 1 result per salesId, it should show the row with the highest score, or in the case of a tie, the most recent lastServiceDate from the Customer table.

Right now, my test data looks like this:

```
id  customerId  salesId  score  lastServiceDate
1   950         418      3      2009-08-09 00:00:00.000
2   951         418      3      2009-08-19 00:00:00.000
3   952         418      1      2009-08-22 00:00:00.000
4   953         419      2      2009-08-15 00:00:00.000
```

I want something that would return, in this instance, just two rows--id 2 (top score/lastServiceDate for salesId 418) and id 4 (only result for salesId 419). In the end, I need to take the data in this table, and insert it into a JobResult table, selecting customerId, and salesId from @results, with these restrictions.

(This finishes a question asked in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343647](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343647/).)

Comment: For what it's worth this is a "table variable", as identified by the @ sign whereas #results is a temp table. @ is in memory, # is on disk.

Comment: So you want 1 row per salesId regardless of the customer?  What if salesId 3 serviced two customers on the same date and each received the exact same score?  What should be inserted to your JobResult table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the data you want:

```
SELECT id, salesId, score, lastServiceDate
 from (select id, salesId, score, lastServiceDate
         ,row_number() over(partition by SalesId order by score desc, lastServiceDate desc) ranking
        from @results) xx
 where xx.ranking = 1
```

and this will delete undesired rows from the table leaving only what you want:

```
DELETE @results
 where id in (select id
               from (select id, salesId, score, lastServiceDate
                       ,row_number() over(partition by SalesId order by score desc, lastServiceDate desc) ranking
                      from @results) xx
               where xx.ranking <> 1)

select * from @results
```

I tested this with the data you posted, but be sure to try it out with larger/more complex data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  WITH highscore AS (
       SELECT r.salesid,
              MAX(r.score) 'maxscore',
              MAX(t.lastservicedate) 'maxservicedate'
         FROM @results r
     GROUP BY r.salesid)
  SELECT t.customerid,
         t.salesid,
         t.lastservicedate
    FROM @results t
    JOIN highscore hs ON hs.salesid = t.salesid 
                     AND hs.maxscore = t.score
                     AND hs.maxservicedate = t.lastservice
GROUP BY t.customerid,
         t.salesid
```

Comment: This certainly seems correct for paring down the max score results, but it doesn't seem to work for lastservicedate--it doesn't cut the group apart in this way.

Comment: @Brisbe: Try now, removed lastservicedate from group by

Comment: Updated: Corrected the CTE & subsequent join clauses.

Comment: @rexem:  This doesn't return any results for my test data for salesId 418--the one with the maxscore is not the same as the one with the maxservicedate, resulting in lost data.